# Neutron star - Relativistic mass continuity equation

Tags: general-relativity, astrophysics, neutron-stars

Neutron stars are relativistic objects. Let's suppose that it's static and spherically symmetric, therefore the metric is:

$$
\mathrm{d} s^{2}=c^{2} \mathrm{~d} t^{2} \mathrm{e}^{2 \Phi}-\mathrm{e}^{2 \lambda} \mathrm{d} r^{2}-r^{2}\left(\mathrm{~d} \theta^{2}+\sin ^{2} \theta \mathrm{d} \phi^{2}\right)
$$

Where $\lambda = \lambda(r)$ determines the space-time curvature in the radial direction. Introducing the gravitational mass $m(r)$ we have:

$$
\mathrm{e}^{-\lambda}=\sqrt{1-2 G m(r) /\left(r c^{2}\right)}
$$

And the volume $dV$ in the star is:

$$
\mathrm{d} V=\frac{4 \pi r^{2} \mathrm{~d} r}{\sqrt{1-2 G m(r) /\left( r c^{2}\right)}}
$$

And the mass continuity equation is:

$$
\frac{\mathrm{d} m}{\mathrm{~d} r}=4 \pi r^{2} \rho(r)
$$

I know how to integrate this equation in the Newtonian case.

**Question**

In the relativistic case $dV = dV(m(r),r)$. How can I integrate the mass continuity equation in the relativistic case?

Answer (score 2):

Before answering your question, let me introduce some considerations which are very important for the solution.

1. While you correctly identify $m$ as the *gravitational mass*, in General Relativity this is a different concept from the *baryonic mass*. Roughly speaking, the gravitational mass is the difference between the baryonic one and the binding energy due to gravity.
2. The second distinction one must be aware of is that $\rho(r)$ appearing in Einstein Equations no longer refers to the baryonic mass density, but encloses the local energy density. In a broad sense, this is a bulk consequence of

$$ E = mc^{2} + \frac{p^{2}}{2m} + \ldots $$

Only in the Newtonian limit we can speak of $\rho$ as the mass density. This situation also have another direct consequence:

3. Although $dm/dr = 4\pi r^{2}$ emerges from the mass continuity equation in the Newtonian limit, in General Relativity this equation no longer expresses this concept. As a matter of fact, this equation in GR emerges from

$$G_{00} = \frac{8\pi G}{c^{4}}T_{00}\ .$$

The appropriate general-relativistic version/analogue of *mass continuity* is given by the conservation of the baryon number 4-vector,

$$\nabla_{\mu}(n_{B}u^{\mu}) = 0\ ,$$

where $n_{B}$ is the baryon number density and $u^{\mu}$ is the fluid 4-velocity. By virtue of "Gauss theorem", for the static and spherically symmetric case this expression can be rearranged in terms of the *total number of baryons*

$$N_{B} = 4\pi \int^{r}_{0} dx\, x^{2}e^{\Lambda(x)} n_{B}(x)\ ,$$

where we assumed the baryonic number density solely depends on the radial coordinate. We can also turn this into a supplementary differential equation,

$$\frac{dN_{B}}{dr} = 4\pi r^{2}e^{\Lambda(r)}n_{B}(r)\\ $$
$$ = \frac{4\pi r^{2}n_{B}(r)}{\sqrt{1 - \frac{2Gm(r)}{c^{2}r}}}\ .$$

In particular, notice this expression preserves the expected relation $dN_{B} = n_{B}dV$.

4. The majority (if not all) Equations of State (EOS) for neutron stars are functional relations of the form $\rho(n_{B})$, $P(n_{B})$. By virtue of the composition of functions and of these being invertible, we can also write $\rho(P)$ and $n_{B}(P)$.

Now, the proper answer. For clarity, let us write down the set of equations describing the structure of a neutron star:

**EOS**

$$\rho(P(r))\ \ \ ,\ \ n_{B}(P(r))\ .$$

**Structure**

$$\frac{dm}{dr} = 4\pi r^{2}\rho(r)\\
\frac{dP}{dr} = -\frac{(P(r) + \rho(r) c^{2})e^{2\Lambda(r)}}{r^{2}}\left[\frac{Gm(r)}{c^{2}} + \frac{4\pi r^{3}GP(r)}{c^{4}}\right]$$

**Volume and baryon number**

$$ \frac{dN_{B}}{dr} =  \frac{4\pi r^{2}n_{B}(r)}{\sqrt{1 - \frac{2Gm(r)}{c^{2}r}}}\\
\frac{dV}{dr} = \frac{4\pi r^{2}}{\sqrt{1 - \frac{2Gm(r)}{c^{2}r}}}$$

(Ignore for now the boundary conditions). Treated as functions of $r$, **we see the structure equations are independent of $N_{B}(r)$ and $V(r)$ but these later functions explicitly depend of $m(r)$ and implicitly of $P(r)$.**

Therefore, you can proceed in two ways for integrating these equations:

1. *Sequentially*. First solve the structure, then the volume and the baryon number as now you know $P(r)$ and $m(r)$.
2. *Simultaneously*.

In either case, the initial conditions ($r=0$) for $N_{B}$, $V$ and $m$ are the same, i.e. $ = 0$; the central density $\rho_{c}$ determines, throughout the EOS, $P_{c} = P(\rho_{c})$ and $n_{B} = n_{B}(\rho_{c})$. Finally, the radius of the star $r_{\ast}$ is determined as the coordinate where $P(r_{\ast}) = 0$.